# How to get ${project.name} of child project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

Referring to ${project.name} in a child pom seems to include the parent name, e.g.

```
parent-name/child-name
```

Is there a way to just get the child-name (i.e, the name of the pom that is actually running)?

I'm might be ok with using the artifactId or anything else that is unique to the child, but that has the same problem

Comment: `${project.artifactId}` does NOT include the parent artifactId.

Comment: First question: Why do you need the project name in a child pom?

Comment: Trying to define <scm> in the parent.  Repo is `https://repo`.  For a given child, repo is `https://repo/${project.artifactId}`. . But the artifactId is a concatenation of the parent id and the child id.   Not sure why it would be unusual to want to reference the name of a project in the child pom.  But artifactId would work the same for me